# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid()Z in JavaFx

Tags: ubuntu, javafx

I have a machine with **Ubuntu 16.10 (yakkety)** and it runs a javafx application perfectly. but I'm getting this exception when I try to run the same application in another machine with **Ubuntu 18.10 (cosmic)** even though I have the same **openjfx** package (*8u102-b14-1*). Other openjfx bionic packages don't work either.

Run command:

```
java -jar target/app.jar
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid()Z
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid()Z
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._isDisplayValid(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.isDisplayValid(GtkApplication.java:83)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:67)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatformFactory.java:41)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:257)
    ... 9 more
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: I've faced this problem on some mixed-release version of Debian and the problem was that I had `openjfx` of Java 8 and `libopenjfx-jni` of Java 11, check that you have proper version of `libopenjfx-jni`, it should have `libglass.so`, which seems to be unavailable on problematic machine.

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it was solved following Pavius's advice. Unattended upgrades in Ubuntu was the reason behind the change of version.

Answer (score 1):

In **Ubuntu 18** I downgrade `openfx`, `libopenjfx-java`, `libopenjfx-jni`:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 \
                     libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 \
                     openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the same versions of `libopenjfx-java` and `libopenjfx-jni` and aren't mixing java 8 and java 11.